# jQueryを用いたスライダーでページナビゲーションごとスライドさせるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQueryを用いたスライダーでページナビゲーション（左右に表示されるものではなく、ページ下部にスライドさせるスライダーの枚数のリンクを表示したナビゲーションです）をスライド画像ごとスライドさせるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。
良い案が見つからず悩んでいるのでご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご教示いただきたいです。

スライダーはbxsliderを使用する想定ですが、他のスライダープラグイン等でも構いません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

bxsliderにはセレクタ（質問者様の言葉で言うとページナビゲーション）をカスタムできるようなので

http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors
画像だけではなくて
画像とカスタムセレクタ自体をスライドさせるようにしてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 上記リンク拝見しました。私がスライドと一緒に動かしたい箇所は「ページャー」に該当します。
[http://bxslider.com/options](http://bxslider.com/options)　Pagerの箇所ご参照。
こちらのオプションのデモを試したり、ページャーの要素ブロックをスライド要素内に入れてみたりしたものの希望の動きになりませんでした。
bxsliderで私が希望する動きを実装するには、プラグイン本体の改変が必要でしょうか。

また、別のスライダープラグインで、希望する動きが見つかりましたので、ご紹介します。
[http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)　デモのSlider Syncingの箇所になります。

Comment: なるほど勘違いしていました。失礼しました。ちなみに見つかったプラグインを利用することは難しいのでしょうか？

Comment: bxsliderでの実装が難しそうな場合はslickの利用も視野に入れております。
後学のためにbxsliderでできるか検証をできたらと考えております。

Answer (score 1):

サムネイルページャーをスライドさせたいとのことで
bxsliderで行う方としては
http://bxslider.com/options#onSliderLoad

Callback関数が用意されているのでスライドを2つ用意して
スライドA（メイン用）とスライドB（サムネイル用）
自分のスライドが動いたタイミングで別のスライドを動かすという方法ができると思います。

スライドBが動く→スライドBのコールバックが働く→スライドBのコールバック中にスライドAをスライドさせる関数を記述する

とすることでサムネイルページャーもスライド化できると思います。